# Escaping HTML for JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I would like to display an unsafe text (from user) in a HTML-enabled JLabel, for example `<html><p>Unsafe user input here</p></html>`. What should I do to escape the user supplied string data to fit into my HTML enabled environment without causing any troubles?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584263/how-to-disable-the-automatic-html-support-of-jlabel

Comment: Answers uses nonstandard com.sun.* components and-or ends up using JList (which is not an answer for me).

Comment: Do you mean something like [`StringEscapeUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml%28java.lang.String%29)?

Comment: @DuncanJones More or less. It is a third party lib. Bringing in a lib just to do that simple thing is not pleasant. Can standard Java API help me? If they accept (even expect) HTML inputs then they should provide basic HTML utilities. At least escaping IMHO. I could write my own escaping (not that difficult - 5 lines), but that would not be future proof.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Which characters need to be escaped on HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381974/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-on-html) I propose the following code:

```
public class SimpleEscaping {

    private static final Pattern[] patterns = new Pattern[]{
        Pattern.compile("&"),
        Pattern.compile("<"),
        Pattern.compile(">")
    };
    private static final String[] replacements = {
        "&amp;",
        "&lt;",
        "&gt;"
    };

    public static String escapeHTML(String input) {
        for (int i = 0; i < patterns.length; i++)
            input = patterns[i].matcher(input).replaceAll(replacements[i]);
        return input;
    }
}
```