# Java: Displaying HTML code in a JTable as plain text

Tags: java, html, swing

As soon as I have some string like `<html><i>something <b>bold</b></i></html>` and I display that in a standard cell of a JTable it get's interpreted and shown as "*something **bold***".

Is there some simple solution / what is best practice to show the HTML code as plain text? So I see in the JTable cell the original `<html><i>something<b>bold</b></i></html>`?

Can't be that difficult, but I don't see how to work around the automatism in JTable. Thanks.

ps: this was no real duplicate as it wasn't asking for JLabel but for JTable, the solution from [How to disable the automatic HTML support of JLabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584263) would disable HTML in all columns, the accepted answer does what I asked for, the answer in the suggested duplicate does not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable the automatic HTML support of JLabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584263/how-to-disable-the-automatic-html-support-of-jlabel) should work the same for `JTable`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer So, where's the JLabel in the JTable where I can `.putClientProperty("html.disable", Boolean.TRUE)`?

Comment: you can call `.putClientProperty("html.disable", Boolean.TRUE)` on the `JTable` as well

Comment: @XtremeBaumer - but then all columns won't show HTML - managed to write my own renderer just like Gnanasekaran Palanisamy suggested below

Comment: well, if you would have stated it earlier that just some columns should show the plain html and not all, then you would have gotten a solution sooner

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I am not able to make a JTable display raw (non-interpreted) HTML (in a String value) merely by calling `JTable.putClientProperty("html.disable", Boolean.TRUE);`. Instead, I need to set the default cell renderer to one that explicitly has that property set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    public TestFrame() {
        super("Sample Project");
        setSize(500, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static class RawHtmlRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        public RawHtmlRenderer() {
            putClientProperty("html.disable", Boolean.TRUE);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] str) {
        Object[][] rowData = new Object[][] {
                { "test", "<html><i>something<b>bold</b></i></html>" },
                { "test", "test" }, { "test", "123" } };
        String[] header = new String[] { "Column 1", "Column 2" };
        JTable table = new JTable(rowData, header);
        TestFrame frame = new TestFrame();
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer( new RawHtmlRenderer() );
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: This can be done by calling `JTable.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, tcr)` where `tcr` is simply a `DefaultTableCellRenderer` whose "client property" has been set. There is no need for a subclass of `DefaultTableCellRenderer`, but the `TableModel` must return `String.class` for each column you wish to customize in this way. Or, you can use `JTable.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, tcr)` and your model does not need to change.